# Probability of getting a certain card depending on how they are dealt and number of players

Tags: probability

I'm trying to calculate the probabilities of getting certain cards in a game, but I've contradicted myself a bit in some parts when trying to calculate something in different ways. Obviously, some of the ways which I'm calculating must be wrong but I can't realise which is the correct one, I must be missing something.

So, the only relevant rules to the question are how cards are dealt. The game is played with a **40-card** Spanish deck (4 suits, 10 cards each). **3 cards are dealt** to each player. Order doesn't matter, and a card obviously can't be repeated. Let's say there are two players, A and B. **Cards are dealt in this order: ABABAB**

---

First off, there are $40*39*38=59280$ possible hands in the game. But that's if I'm dealing only to myself, but since there are 2 players, this number varies for each of them.

So with two players, A would get $40*38*36=54720$ possible hands and B would get $39*37*35=50505$ possible hands, right? A has 40 possible cards first, then 38 (discounting the one he already has and the one B has) and so on.

Problem comes when I try to calculate the probabilty of each player getting a single particular card (say, the Ace of Swords). I have several ways, but they all give me different results and can't find which is the right one.

First option I thought, calculate how many possible hands have the card. $40*39*1=1482$ if I'm correct: first you have 40 cards in the deck, then 39, then only one option (the ace of swords). Then divide this number by the number of possible hands for A and for B separately, giving me $0,02708333333$ and $0,02934362934$. Something seems suspicious... how can B have more chances of getting this card if he has a disadvantage when being dealt the cards? But I can't find what I did wrong in the numbers

Other thing I tried, calculate how many possible hands have the ace of swords separately for A and B, then divide those two numbers by the total possible hands (59280). A has $40*38*1=1520$ possible hands, B has $39*37*1=1443$. $1520/59280=0,02564102564$ and $1443/59280=0,02434210526$. Now A has more chances to get the card, which makes sense, but I still suspect this answer because it's very different from the following thing I tried. I don't know if it is a coincidence, but the average of 1520 and 1443 is $1481,5$, really close to 1482.

And the other thing I tried is just multiplying the chances of getting the card in each card of the hand, for each player. So for A, $\frac {1}{40}*\frac {1}{38}*\frac {1}{36}=0,0000182748538$ and for B $\frac {1}{39}*\frac {1}{37}*\frac {1}{35}=0,0000198000198$. But still something seems off, the number is much lower than in the other two tries, and B has more chances somehow

---

So, which is the correct way to calculate this? How do I discount the cards already dealt (or burned if I were to calculate that scenario too)? What am I doing wrong? Please correct me if I used wrong language, I don't know much advanced mathematical vocabulary in English

I was planning to extend this to include other scenarios (more players, burning cards, dealing AAABBB) but I think I can work those out if I find the answer to this one

Comment: the first part is not correct: both players have the same possible number of different hands.

Comment: And that number is $40\choose 3$ because every player can get every single possible combination of three cards. And in addition the probability each player gets each hands are all equal because of symmetry of cards. Very counter-intuitive though, I agree. Essentially the probability player $B$ gets the hand $X,Y,Z$ does not change with or without the presence of player $A$, or the hand of cards a player get is independent of the other player.

Comment: Oh, I see. But if we go to the second part, seeing how probable it is that a player gets a particular card. Wouldn't B have less chances? There's the slim chance that A got that card first

Comment: That's what intuition would tell us, but in fact because there is the big chance that $A$ did not get that card first too, the probability is actually independent of $A$. Basically if $A$ did not get the card first, $B$ would have a bigger chance of getting the card. And after the two cases balance out, it would turned out the probability $B$ gets a hand is equal to as if $A$ does not exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you want to know the probability that a card is in the hand of player $A$ without knowing the cards that were dealt, that is, you deal two hands and wants to know what is the probability that in the hand $A$ is some card.

If $A$ is the first player to be deal this is the same to ask for the probability that a card land in positions $1,3$ or $5$ of a random set of six ordered cards, that is, the probability that it is in first place is $1/40$, more the probability that it is in the third place, that it is $\frac{39}{40}\cdot\frac{38}{39}\cdot\frac1{38}=\frac1{40}$, what means the probability that is not in first and second place and it is in the third place.

More the probability that it is in fifth place, that in a similar fashion to the previous probability is also $\frac1{40}$. Then the total is

$$\frac{3}{40}\approx 7.5\%$$

The previous analysis shows, as pointed by @cr001, that the probability that a card appear after $X$ draws is independent of the previous draws if they are unknown. A different case is if we have some information about the cards that had been drawn previously.

Comment: Oh, I see. I was grossly overthinking this. So the cards dealt to one player wouldn't affect the other's probabilities. So I guess ABABAB vs AAABBB dealing wouldn't affect that either, the only effect it could have is to prevent cheating or mitigate the effects of poor shuffling. And if we do have some information about the cards, how does it change the probabilities? Say, 1 to 3 cards are burned and shown to players before dealing

Comment: you are destroying three cards if you burn them, so you have now a deck of $37$ cards. If some of the cards that you want was burnt then the probability that you get it is zero. By other cards proceed in the same way as a deck of $37$ cards. But it is more interesting if you know *partial* information, that is, if you dont know exactly what cards had burnt but you know that two of them were bigger than $X$ or of some "type", etc.